# CyanogenMod: enable to build CM10.2.zip: recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, samsung-mobile, cyanogenmod

I am trying to build CM10.2 for Samsung S4 over in Ubuntu 12.04.4 (64-bit system) following this link. After following each step to the letter, I am unable to generate the cm-[something].zip file.

Here's what I got after the build finished:

```
Note: some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
make: ** [/.../android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LINERARIES/framework_intermediates/noproguard.classes-with-local.dex] killed
make: ** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

afterward, when I execute:

```
# cd $OUT
```

and then:

```
ls -l
```

I see the following list:

- android-info.txt
- clean_steps.mk
- data external
- fake_packages
- kernel
- obj
- previous_build_config.mk
- recovery
- root
- symbols
- system
- userdata.img

As you can see there is no **cm-[something].zip** file.

what do these notes mean ?

why the cm-[something].zip file is not generated ?

and how to "recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details." while building Cyanogenmod?

Thanks ...

Comment: since the "make" is "killed" it means the build was't complete .. although, I didn't get this very specific error, but I guess it's a memory issue .. how much is your RAM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just increase your memory size to at least 4GB and it should work ...